# Are you immune to the 5 death rule after you acquire the glow effect to your file stars?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

Once you complete the game you are given stars that are located on your file. You acquire different stars for different goals that you accomplish, up to 5. My question lies with the glowing or shiny stars, I know that if you don't die over 5 times in a single level then your accomplishment stars will all glow. What I was wondering was if you've already received the glow effect are you immune to the 5 death rule from then on while trying to accomplish the other goals? Or will the glow disappear?

I'm sure you know what I'm referencing but in case you don't:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is you're immune from the point at which you see the credits roll for the first time. All of the bonus content is much harder, and in those stages, five or more deaths ceases to trigger the game's assist features.

I've 100% completed the game with glowy stars intact, by the way. My worst playthrough of a level after the main game was around 50 deaths. Oh, how I wish that were hyperbole.

(As spoiler-free as I can make this.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am let say.. 90% done and i've simply gotten into the habit of hitting the home button if i die. I didn't want to risk losing my special little stars.

Comment: No problem. This advice is corroborated from a few sources I'd read while working through the game, including here: http://www.gamespot.com/super-mario-3d-land/forum/i-already-have-2-shiny-stars-will-they-be-shiny-forever-61050272 and, now, here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/620831-/61148638, which also points out that deaths on levels you'd previously completed don't count.

Comment: Nicely done Gomez, mucho help.